# Navigate to Location settings page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working on a Xamarin forms project in visual studio 2017 .I need to open Location settings page and allow user to turn on location services .Is there any way i can do this in shared project for Android and IOS or do i have to create specific methods in each Android and IOS projects .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need platform specification and you will find a full tutorial about how achieving this at Xamarin Forums [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/319176/#Comment_319176).

Comment: Thanks , I really appreciate it